# How to determine the complexity of a single line in a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, big-o, code-complexity

Right now I'm trying to find the "fundamental step" in a Python function. The fundamental step is the point in the code that is complexity `O(1)` on its own. I'm having a tough time finding it in this function:

```
def mystery1(numbers): 
    n = len(numbers)
    total = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(numbers):
        j = i
        while j < len(numbers):
            total += numbers[i]*numbers[j]
            j += 2
        numbers[i] = total
        i += 3
```

I'd like to think that the fundamental step here is infact `total += numbers[i]*numbers[j]` because it should be executed more times than any other statement in the function, however I'm not totally convinced in my ability to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: probably because it is everywhere, all the operations are 0(1) in your code

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh... I suppose I should have realized that. So should I assume whichever portion of the code is executed most frequently is infact the fundamental step?

Comment: Not necessarily - it is possible to have lines which have higher complexity. E.g. list comprehension, `foo in bar` type lines, etc.

Comment: MAria, I believe the OP refers to this particular piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

O(1) is the runtime of an algorithm that does not depend on the size of an input.

In your case:

```
def mystery1(numbers): 
    n = len(numbers) # -> Likely O(1) since one simply needs to
                     # use log() to find the number of digits in a number.
    total = 0 # -> O(1) since you're simply assigning a value to memory.
    i = 0 # -> O(1) since you're simply assigning a value to memory.
    while i < len(numbers): # -> O(n) since the loop is dependent on n, 
                            # which is the length of numbers
        j = i # -> O(1) since you're simply assigning a value to memory.
        while j < len(numbers): # -> O(n) since the loop is dependent on n, 
                                # which is the length of numbers
            total += numbers[i]*numbers[j] # -> O(1) since you're simply 
                                           # adding two values from memory.
            j += 2 # -> O(1) since you're simply incrementing by 2
        numbers[i] = total # -> O(1) since you're simply assigning a value to memory.
        i += 3 # -> O(1) since you're simply assigning a value to memory.
```